# Codename One Focus and Removing Components

Tags: codenameone

I have implemented code in focusGained that in some cases may cause the component (a container I have set to be focusable) which just received that focus to be removed from the screen, and replaced in the container by another component.  This will also cause a redraw of the screen to show the changed component.

This does work but I have a bit of a problem, in that the next component in the container also gains focus and so my code removes/replaces it also.  I assume this is because on the redraw, that component now occupies the same space where the tap originally occurred.

If the last component in the container was originally selected, then the replacement component is itself given focus and so it is removed and replaced.

Any ideas on what I may have miscoded or anything I can do to avoid the second focusGained call?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you did something wrong. If we remove the component with the focus we'll find the next available one. The replace method doesn't take focus into consideration but can't grant focus to a component that isn't physically here yet so it's granted to the next component. Not much to do here.

You can `requstFocus()` after the transition completes to fix the order manually.